# make a query with pyqt5 and excel

Tags: python, excel, pyqt5

I want to make a query with PyQt5 and excel.

I put a number in a text field and it shows the result of another column in the same row in a label.

I want to search for an id and get the name to put in a label.

```
        self.line = self.findChild(QLineEdit, "lineEdit")
        self.button = self.findChild(QPushButton, "pushButton")
        self.label = self.findChild(QLabel, "label")
        self.textBrowser = self.findChild(QTextBrowser, "textBrowser")
        
        
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.clicker)

        self.show()

    def clicker(self):
        wb = load_workbook('book.xlsx')
        ws = wb.active
        

        self.textBrowser.setText(str(ws["C2"].value))
```

[image: 1]

[all code](https://replit.com/@devilonline/teste123#main.py)

Comment: OT: I'm assuming you're using a pyuic file or uic loaded UI. Despite what some tutorials suggest, there's absolutely **no** need for `findChild`, as `uic` automatically creates the references based on the object name. For instance, the QLineEdit will be already accessible as `self.lineEdit` (or `self.ui.lineEdit` if you created an instance of the form class named `self.ui`).

Comment: there is my all code in the link. can you give me an example? thanks

Comment: Sorry, but no. Questions should always be self-contained. Please [edit] your question and provide a valid [mre]. Besides, remember that StackOverflow is not a tutorial website, we require *specific, detailed questions*, and some amount of research efforts in trying to solve problems. Right now I cannot see any of that in your code. Please show what you tried to do, even if it didn't work as expected.